# Attempting to include a Library in Xcode, file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, include, libraries, eigen

I'm trying to create a program that uses a lot of linear algebra and OpenGL, and a colleague of mine recommended that I use the Eigen library to make things a lot simpler. After downloading and extracting the library off of Eigen's official website and I clicked on the project, found the "Link Binary with Libraries" option, went into to the folder that resulted from the unarchiving (eigen-eigen-bdd17ee3b1b3), and then found the Eigen folder. This folder contains all of the header files.

The library showed up on the sidebar, and when I go into the correct sub-folder the header files were all there too. According to the Eigen website, you only need the header files for the includes to work, but no matter how I set up the filepath in the include statement, even if what I can physically see what I'm including on the sidebar, XCode tells me it can't find the file. I'm using an older version of XCode 4. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing header search paths:

[image]

Comment: All those... images... will be lost, in time, like tears... in... rain. Time... to summarize.

Comment: When I select "header search paths" that box doesn't pop up. Showing the dropdown menu gives me the options "debug" and "release" which let me add things, but not in the way seen in your image. Should I put the path in one of those?

Comment: Double click on the right side should give you option to add into both at the same time if I remember correctly.